# Weirdness with Interpolation of data and InverseFunction

Tags: bugs, interpolation, inverse

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persisting through 13.1.0**

---

Something strange is happening with this list of data:

```
list={{1., 1.62253*10^9}, {1.5, 1.36608*10^9}, {2., 1.13736*10^9}, {2.5, 
      9.44041*10^8}, {3., 7.82907*10^8}, {3.5, 6.49117*10^8}, {4., 
      5.38152*10^8}, {4.5, 4.46147*10^8}, {5., 3.6987*10^8}, {5.5, 
      3.06633*10^8}, {6., 2.54208*10^8}, {6.5, 2.10746*10^8}, {7., 
      1.74714*10^8}, {7.5, 1.44843*10^8}, {8., 1.20079*10^8}, {8.5, 
      9.95493*10^7}, {9., 8.25292*10^7}, {9.5, 6.84191*10^7}, {10., 
      5.67215*10^7}, {10.5, 4.70237*10^7}, {11., 3.8984*10^7}, {11.5, 
      3.23189*10^7}, {12., 2.67933*10^7}, {12.5, 2.22124*10^7}, {13., 
      1.84148*10^7}, {13.5, 1.52664*10^7}, {14., 1.26563*10^7}, {14.5, 
      1.04924*10^7}, {15., 8.69852*10^6}, {15.5, 7.21132*10^6}, {16., 
      5.9784*10^6}, {16.5, 4.95627*10^6}, {17., 4.10889*10^6}, {17.5, 
      3.40639*10^6}, {18., 2.824*10^6}, {18.5, 2.34117*10^6}, {19., 
      1.9409*10^6}, {19.5, 1.60906*10^6}, {20., 1.33396*10^6}, {20.5, 
      1.10589*10^6}, {21., 916817.}, {21.5, 760068.}, {22., 
      630118.}, {22.5, 522387.}, {23., 433074.}, {23.5, 359031.}, {24., 
      297647.}, {24.5, 246758.}, {25., 204570.}, {25.5, 169594.}, {26., 
      140598.}, {26.5, 116560.}, {27., 96631.8}, {27.5, 80110.6}, {28., 
      66414.}, {28.5, 55059.1}, {29., 45645.6}, {29.5, 37841.5}, {30., 
      31371.7}, {30.5, 26008.}, {31., 21561.4}, {31.5, 17874.9}, {32., 
      14818.7}, {32.5, 12284.9}, {33., 10184.1}, {33.5, 8442.19}, {34., 
      6997.53}, {34.5, 5798.9}, {35., 4803.48}, {35.5, 3975.26}, {36., 
      3283.38}, {36.5, 2700.58}, {37., 2201.3}, {37.5, 1759.49}, {38., 
      1347.12}, {38.5, 944.464}, {39., 592.687}, {39.5, 359.675}, {40., 
      218.154}, {40.5, 132.317}, {41., 80.2543}, {41.5, 48.6767}, {42., 
      29.5239}, {42.5, 17.9072}, {43., 10.8612}, {43.5, 6.58768}, {44., 
      3.99563}, {44.5, 2.42347}, {45., 1.46991}, {45.5, 0.891545}, {46., 
      0.54075}, {46.5, 0.327981}, {47., 0.198931}, {47.5, 0.120658}, {48.,
       0.0731825}, {48.5, 0.0443874}, {49., 0.0269223}, {49.5, 
      0.0163292}, {50., 0.00990417}, {50.5, 0.00600718}, {51., 
      0.00364354}, {51.5, 0.00220992}, {52., 0.00134038}, {52.5, 
      0.000812984}, {53., 0.0004931}, {53.5, 0.00029908}, {54., 
      0.000181401}, {54.5, 0.000110025}, {55., 0.0000667338}, {55.5, 
      0.0000404761}, {56., 0.00002455}, {56.5, 0.0000148903}, {57., 
      9.03144*10^-6}, {57.5, 5.47784*10^-6}, {58., 3.32248*10^-6}, {58.5, 
      2.01519*10^-6}, {59., 1.22227*10^-6}, {59.5, 7.41345*10^-7}, {60., 
      4.49649*10^-7}}
```

If I interpolate them with

```
T = Interpolation[list]
```

I get a nice decreasing function, which behaves like

```
LogPlot[T[b], {b, 1, 60}, AxesLabel -> {"b", "T"}]
```

[image]

The problems begin when I try to define the inverse of T as

```
b = InverseFunction[T]
```

because when I evaluate it from `10^-7` up to `10^5` everything is right, as the following graph shows,

[image]

but at the orders of magnitude `10^6`, `10^7` and `10^8` it fails and gives simply (e.g. for the `10^6` case)

[image]

Moreover, around `10^9` it starts again giving the right values (around 2).

What could be the issue?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Especially suspicious is that addition of `InterpolationOrder -> 1` doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: A bug? Oh dear.. I am using _Mathematica 12.0 Student Edition_, I don't know if it can help...

Comment: One workaround is to start from the inverse problem: `b = Interpolation[Reverse /@ list]; T = InverseFunction[b];`. Then everything works as expected. I recommend reporting the original problem to the support though. Of course, this approach isn't equivalent to the original and could provide identical results only for `InterpolationOrder -> 1`.

Comment: Oh wonderful! Thank you very much! How can I report the problem? I think that the order of interpolation is nice with 1.

Comment: You can go to `Help > Give Feedback...` in *Mathematica* or just write a letter to support at wolfram.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in `InverseFunction`. Even addition of `InterpolationOrder -> 1` to `Interpolation` doesn't solve the problem.

The function values are all machine numbers, contain no duplicate points and are strictly decreasing as easily can be seen from `Sign[Differences /@ Transpose[list]]`. It is a shame that that *Mathematica* fails for such a basic task.

One workaround is to start from the inverse problem:

```
b = Interpolation[Reverse /@ list]; T = InverseFunction[b];
```

Then everything works as expected. Of course, this approach isn't equivalent to the original and could provide identical results only for `InterpolationOrder -> 1`. I recommend reporting the original problem to the support.

Here is a minimal code snippet reproducing the issue:

```
list = {{20., 1.3*^6}, {20.5, 1.1*^6}, {21., 920000.}, {21.5`, 760000.}};
int = Interpolation[list];
if = InverseFunction[int];
if[1*^6]
```

> [image: screenshot]

The inverse function returns unevaluated even for `int = Interpolation[list, InterpolationOrder -> 1]`.